# Does laptop in clamshell mode go to sleep when unplugged?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, closed-clamshell

If I am using a laptop in clamshell mode, and then I unplug the screen and disconnect the power without opening up the laptop, will it automatically go to sleep or will it stay turned on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testing this just now on my personal rMBP, it does **not** go to sleep immediately. It appears to trigger the sleep at the normal "power adapter sleep" time.a

Comment: How exactly did you test this?  Since the machine has no HDD and has a tendency not to spin up the fans, I couldn't just listen to it.

Answer (score 0):

Under Settings > Energy Saver, you can dictate how it behaves while on battery or while plugged in.

If the Battery sleep setting is set to a particular timespan, it will sleep after that amount of inactivity. If set to "Never", then it will stay on until the battery gets low enough that the safe-sleep mode kicks in.